# EXTJS4 - TinyMCE and wkhtmltopdf and the case of the missing fonts

Tags: php, fonts, wkhtmltopdf

I have a cunning plan that uses a TinyMCE editor embedded in EXTJS4 to produce HTML output that I can then produce PDF's from and I've almost got the whole thing working. The one thing I'm having a problem with is fonts. TinyMCE can handle them no problem, but I can't get them to work at all with wkhtmltopdf. When I use any font (even the bolding text button) my ajax request aborts and crashes the browser. I have to restart the browser to go any further. If I just use the default font the pdf's are produced correctly.

I've tried putting the user-style-sheet in every conceivable place to get it to pick it up but to no avail.

Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.
I'm using wkhtmltopdf 0.11.0_rc1 on windows 7 with xampp.

```
POST VARS Sent to PHP via AJAX
cgroup  54
htmlx   <p><span style="font-family: trebuchet ms,geneva;">this is a test in TREBUCHET MS</span></p><p>THIS IS NORMAL TEXT ag</p>
messagetype post
send_date   18 Jun 2012
send_time   3:25 PM
subject 
task    test  


PHP Script

$outfile = './tmp/'.$timestamp.'.pdf';
$wkhtmloptions = "--header-spacing 5 --footer-spacing 2 --margin-top 15 --user-style-sheet file:///".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/arx/wkhtmltopdf.css";

$pdf = new wkhtmltopdf(array( 
    'title'         => 'Title',
      'html'          => $htmlx,
      'tmppath'       => 'tmp', 
      'binpath'       => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/arx/bin/wkhtmltopdf/', 
      'options'       => $wkhtmloptions,
    ));

    $pdf->output('F', $outfile); //save the file to $outfile 
    $msg = "Test PDF generated";
    $success =true; 

    echo "{success: $success, msg: '$msg', title: 'Test Message', type: '$type', data: '$outfile'}";


wkhtmltopdf.css located in htdocs/arx/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'trebuchet MS';
    src: url('resources/fonts/trebuc.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'trebuchet MS';
    src: url('./resources/fonts/trebucit.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'trebuchet MS';
    src: url('./resources/fonts/trebucbd.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'trebuchet MS';
    src: url('./resources/fonts/trebucbi.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You control the HTML, so you could simply edit the incoming HTML and not use `--user-style-sheet` at all. Would something like this for the input html work for you?

```
 <html><head>
   <!-- if you really need it -->
   <link href="http://server/arx/wkhtmltopdf.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head><body>
   <p><span style="font-family: comic sans ms;">TREBUCHET MS</span></p>
   <p>THIS IS NORMAL TEXT ag</p>
 </body></html>
```

This could also be due to a number of issues, but more details would help.

- Do you see the wkhtmltopdf process starting?
- Have you tried using a font directly without the CSS definitions?
- Do you need the CSS?
- Do you see an outfile being generated?
- Does it work if you execute it directly from the command line? Running directly might give you output that is lost when you use wkhtmltopdf programmatically.